# AnalogClock - changing hand-drawables every 30 minutes?

Tags: android, widget

I am not necessarily looking for a full solution, but whether or not there is a good way to trigger a change of graphics for the minute and hour hands in an AnalogClock at a certain time.

I want to do this because the hands are not symmetric, thus I want to mirror for example the minute hand every time it hits 30 min and 0 min.

Answer (score 0):

you can put your Thread to sleep for 30 minutes and after cycling it'll sleep for 30 min again

```
Thread.sleep((30*60*1000));
```

maybe post part of your code for better solution.